# How to create a nested repository in ontotext GraphDB?

Tags: graphdb

GraphDB seems to have a feature to create nested repository. As given in their [documentation](https://graphdb.ontotext.com/documentation/9.8/free/nested-repositories.html) , it seems to be possible to create one using the UI. Can anyone guide me on how to create this and which page has this feature? Thanks in advance.

I tried to explore the UI to create the repositories but couldn't find the feature to create nested repositories.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nested repositories are no longer supported. You could similar results with the SPARQL Federation - https://graphdb.ontotext.com/documentation/10.1/sparql-federation.html